# Batch parameters in IF. syntax error

Tags: batch-file

this is the start of a code I want to use as a cronjob. Based on the Parameter you enter you start the script in different modes.

The Problem is, if I  enter a wrong or no parameter I get a Syntax error instead of the Usage echo.

"-v" cannot be processed syntactically at this Point.

```
   @ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set v=False
set q=False

        if  %1 EQU -v (
            set v=True
        ) else (
        if  %1 EQU -q (
            set q=True
        ) else (
            ECHO  %DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,2%%DATE:~-10,2%_%Time% WARN False Parameter   %1 >> C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,2%%DATE:~-10,2%_Log_2.34.log
REM Usage

            echo Usage  [-v]    for verbose mode
            echo        [-q]    for quiet mode
            echo.

            pause
            goto EOF
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer.

```
   @ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set v=False
set q=False

        if /i "%~1" EQU "-v" (
            set v=True
        ) else (
        if /i "%~1" EQU "-q" (
            set q=True
        ) else (
            ECHO  %DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,2%%DATE:~-10,2%_%Time% WARN False Parameter   %1 >> C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,2%%DATE:~-10,2%_Log_2.34.log
REM Usage

            echo Usage  [-v]    for verbose mode
            echo        [-q]    for quiet mode
            echo.

            pause
            goto EOF
        )
    )
```

/i will accept two words in %1 and will not fail if %1 is empty.

Comment: `/i` means "ignore case", so it will accept `-V` as well as `-v`. Not sure if that's what you intended.

Comment: `/i` is probably a good option to use (ignore case), but it is not what solved your problem. It is the quotes on both sides of the comparison that solved the problem. `if /i  %1 equ -v` fails if `%1` is undefined. Putting quotes around the values solves the problem (the quotes are included in the comparison)